# Select even integers in the linked list and make their sub parts

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

We were tasked to do the following code.

You are given a linked list that contains N integers. You are to perform the following reverse operation on the list:

Select all the subparts of the list that contain only even integers. For example, if the list is {1,2,8,9,12,16}, then the selected subparts will be {2,8}, {12,16}.

Reverse the selected subpart such as {8,2} and {16,12}.

The list should now be {1,8,2,9,16,12}.

The problem is that it is not creating the sublist and give me output like `[2, 8, 12, 16]`, but I want it like `{2,8}, {12,16}`.

Below is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def append_value(self, x):
        if not isinstance(x, Node):
            x = Node(x)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = x
        else:
            self.tail.next = x
        self.tail = x

    def reverse_list_recursive(self, current, previous):
        if self.head is None:
            return
        elif current.next is None:
            self.tail = self.head
            current.next = previous
            self.head = current
        else:
            next = current.next
            current.next = previous
            self.reverse_list_recursive(next, current)

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head is None

    def __str__(self):
        to_print = ''
        current = self.head
        while current:
            to_print += f'{current.data}->'
            current = current.next
        if to_print:
            return f'[{to_print[:-2]}]'
        return '[]'
```

This is my function:

```
    def reverse_sub_parts(self):
        sublist_list = list()
        current = self.head
        while current:
            if current.data % 2 == 0:
                sublist_list.append(current.data)
            current = current.next
        print(sublist_list)


my_list = LinkedList()
my_list.append_value(1)
my_list.append_value(2)
my_list.append_value(8)
my_list.append_value(9)
my_list.append_value(12)
my_list.append_value(16)

my_list.reverse_sub_parts()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is explicitly adding all nodes that have even numbers to a single list (`sublist_list`). The statement `sublist_list = list()` is only executed once, so there is no way you could ever hope to get more than one list like that.

Secondly, even if you manage to create a variable number of lists like that, you would still need to have logic to reverse those new lists (trivial), and to *replace* the original sublists inside the original list with the reversed lists (less trivial).

In the end, it is not making things easier like this.

I would suggest to first make your `reverse_list_recursive` function more versatile, so it can also do the job for a *subsection* of the list, by letting it accept two more arguments: the node the precedes that section, and the node the follows it. Both would be `None` by default, which means that the whole list should be reversed.

I would also suggest to not use a recursive solution, as this will use stack space that is linear with the number of nodes in the list, and so if the list would have like thousands of nodes, you will run into a stack size limit.

So here is an iterative reverse function, that takes these extra, optional arguments:

```
    def reverse(self, before_first=None, after_last=None):
        prev = after_last
        current = before_first.next if before_first else self.head
        while current and current != after_last:
            prev, current.next, current = current, prev, current.next
        if before_first:
            before_first.next = prev
        else:
            self.head = prev
```

Now the hardest part has been done really, as you now only need to identify the nodes that bound the sequences of even-numbered nodes:

```
    def reverse_sub_parts(self):
        prev = None
        current = self.head
        while current:
            if current.data % 2 == 0:
                if not prev or prev.data % 2 == 1:
                    before_start = prev
            elif prev and prev.data % 2 == 0:
                self.reverse(before_start, current)
            prev = current
            current = current.next

        if prev and prev.data % 2 == 0:
            self.reverse(before_start)
```

Comment: What is `prev = None` doing inside `reverse_sub_parts`? Can you explain a bit more how it is reversing the sublist?

Comment: `prev` indicates the node that precedes `current` in the list. Since we start with `current  = self.head`, there is no preceding node, so it is `None`. `prev` walks one step behind `current`, so we know exactly which node came before, also when the links get reversed by the call to `reverse`.